# Filter data in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an `ArrayList` of `String` type, it contains the id of `myEvent`, and I want to compare this id with `ListEvent`. If equals, it will show data in the `RecyclerView`.

But I have a problem, the loop is replacing the data in the `RecyclerView`.

Here is my code:

```
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
            List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                lst.add(String.valueOf(data.getValue()));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("KEY", lst.get(i));
                final Query query = presenter.getQuery(lst.get(i));
                mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, JoinedEventViewHolder>(Event.class, R.layout.item_my_box_joined_event,
                        JoinedEventViewHolder.class, query) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(JoinedEventViewHolder viewHolder, Event model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.bindToEvent(getContext(), model);
                    }
                };
                mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

In one loop, it will replace `myAdapter`.

Comment: Query query = presenter.getQuery(lst.get(i)); in this line , presenter is an object of?

Comment: oppps, sorry, presenter is a class, I 'm using MVC pattern

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mmazzarolo/firebase-recyclerview

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter constructor takes two parameters:

query: The Firebase location to watch for data changes
itemClass: The class of the items (childs)

Comment: What exactly is the point of that GitHub link? I have to ask, I don't see how it contributes to your answer.